# Howto generate sha2_256 in php?

Tags: php, hash, codeigniter-3

I am stuck in generate sha2_256('demo') in PHP. Can anyone help me to generate?

I have one API, which has sha2_256('demo') generated key. I am not able to generate this key in my PHP application. I searched on google, but all codes are related to SQL server, can anyone help me this.

I tried this method but says the wrong key,

```
echo hash('sha256','demo');
```

Comment: Where/how do you get `wrong key`? https://3v4l.org/ubNZF

Comment: can you generate sha2_256 of demo.means like sha2_256('demo').

Comment: That function seems like it is SQL server specific. I've never seen it before. What do you need to do with it in PHP. You could compare the has with the DB by hashing the input `where column = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', ?)`